# Изменить порядок слов в строке SED

Tags: строки, bash, sed, cisco

Есть строка вида

```
access-list outside line 1 extended permit tcp host 10.200.200.200 host 10.100.100.100 eq sqlnet
```

надо получить:

```
access-list outside line 1 extended permit tcp 10.200.200.200 255.255.255.255 10.100.100.100 255.255.255.255 eq sqlnet
```

т.е. при наличии слова host до IP адреса, оно убирается, а после IP адреса надо вписать 255.255.255.255.

Дошел до такого варианта

```
sed -ie 's/host \(.*\) eq/\1 255.255.255.255 eq/' $aclFileInput
```

но он так себе, ибо eq не всегда присутствует в исходной строке.

Если это возможно, то хотелось бы пример с использованием sed, ну или любой bash вариант.

Comment: Вот, все таки что нибудь такое `sed -r 's/host[ \t]+([0-9.]{9,})[^0-9]+([0-9.]{9,})/\1 255.255.255.255 \2 255.255.255.255/g'`

Comment: Спасибо, почти то что нужно. Дело в том что ключевое слово host можно не встречаться, встречаться 1 раз, встречаться 2 раза. Поэтому я чуть видоизменил ваше решение и все заработало:
sed -r 's/host[ \t]+([0-9.]{9,})[^0-9]/\1 255.255.255.255 /g' $aclFileInput > $aclFileOutput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

т.к. в Cisco ACL слово host может встречаться 0, 1, 2 раза. Решение выглядит так:

```
sed -r 's/host[ \t]+([0-9.]{9,})[^0-9]/\1 255.255.255.255 /g' $aclFileInput > $aclFileOutput
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```sh
sed\
    -e 's/\(host \)\(\([[:digit:]]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[[:digit:]]\{1,3\}\)/\2/g'\
    -e 's/\( \([[:digit:]]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[[:digit:]]\{1,3\}\)/\1 255.255.255.255/g'\
    ./tmp.txt
```